# Не работают кнопки на телефоне, в эмуляторе работают

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

Коллеги, возможно кто то сталкивался, на эмуляторе приложение работает нормально, а когда устанавливаю app-debug.apk на телефон, то в приложении не работают кнопки, кнопки даже не реагируют на палец.

Разметка:

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="111dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.017">
```

Код:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        img_play = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.img_play);
        img_play.setEnabled(false);
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        new PlayerTask().execute(stream);
        img_play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (flag)
                    img_play.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause);
                else
                    img_play.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
                flag = !flag;
                if (started) {
                    started = false;
                    mediaPlayer.pause();

                } else {
                    started = true;
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                }
            }
        });

    }
```

Манифест

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="horoshoe.radio.online">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

После того как убрал `img_play.setEnabled(false);` на телефоне приложение вылетает, а на эмуляторе продолжает работать

> java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing
>   doInBackground()
>         at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:318)
>         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
>         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
>         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
>         at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
>         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:760)
>       Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException
>         at android.media.MediaPlayer._prepare(Native Method)
>         at android.media.MediaPlayer.prepare(MediaPlayer.java:1188)
>         at horoshoe.radio.online.MainActivity$PlayerTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:71)
>         at horoshoe.radio.online.MainActivity$PlayerTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:65)
>         at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:304)
>         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)

Comment: Логи покажите, манифест, xml с разметкой и код, где вы назначаете `OnClickListener`. Какая targetSdkVersion?

Comment: Для дополнения вносите правки в сам вопрос. Разметку, кстати, не всю привели. И ещё нужно содержание AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Попробуйте убрать вот эту строку кода: img_play.setEnabled(false);

Comment: Добавил в общий вопрос, что то я не могу разобраться как тут добавлять куски кода, больше 600 символов.

Comment: @Михаил я поправил вопрос и дал ответ ^_^

Comment: Если вам был дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый (:

Answer (score 0):

В общем-то, я так и предполагал. Вероятно, дело в `supportsRtl="true"`.

Если посмотреть [официальную документацию](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element?hl=es#supportsrtl):

> Declares whether your application is willing to support right-to-left
>   (RTL) layouts.
>
> If set to `true` and `targetSdkVersion` is set to `17` or higher, various
>   RTL APIs will be activated and used by the system so your app can
>   display RTL layouts. **If set to `false` or if `targetSdkVersion` is set to
>   `16` or lower**, the RTL APIs will be ignored or will have no effect and
>   your app will behave the same regardless of the layout direction
>   associated to the user's Locale choice (your layouts will always be
>   left-to-right).
>
> The default value of this attribute is `false`.
>
> This attribute was added in API level `17`.

Нужно верстать с оглядкой на этот флаг. Для начала, попробуйте убрать этот флаг и посмотреть. Если на устройстве будет нормально всё, тогда нужно думать над тем, как поменять разметку.

Comment: Изменил на  supportsRtl="false", но все равно на девайсе вылетает.

Comment: @Михаил падение - это другое. Что у вас на 71 строке в `MainActivity`? Если `mp.prepare();`, то замените на `mp.prepareAsync();`

Comment: Спасибо, изменил prepere на prepareAsync приложение запустилось, кнопка работает, но звука нету.

Comment: @Михаил это уже другая проблема. Лучше задайте отдельным вопросом (:

Comment: Ок. Спасибо за разъяснение.

Comment: @Михаил рад помочь. Этот ответ лучше отметить как принятый. В новом вопросе сразу приложите код, чтобы люди могли помочь быстрее.